# How can I achieve a self-referencing many-to-many relationship on the SQLAlchemy ORM back referencing to the same attribute?

Tags: python, many-to-many, sqlalchemy, self-reference

I'm trying to implement a self-referential many-to-many relationship using declarative on SQLAlchemy.

The relationship represents friendship between two users. Online I've found (both in the documentation and Google) how to make a self-referential m2m relationship where somehow the roles are differentiated. This means that in this m2m relationships UserA is, for example, UserB's boss, so he lists him under a 'subordinates' attribute or what have you. In the same way UserB lists UserA under 'superiors'.

This constitutes no problem, because we can declare a backref to the same table in this way:

```
subordinates = relationship('User', backref='superiors')
```

So there, of course, the 'superiors' attribute is not explicit within the class.

Anyway, here's my problem: what if I want to backref to the same attribute where I'm calling the backref? Like this:

```
friends = relationship('User',
                       secondary=friendship, #this is the table that breaks the m2m
                       primaryjoin=id==friendship.c.friend_a_id,
                       secondaryjoin=id==friendship.c.friend_b_id
                       backref=??????
                       )
```

This makes sense, because if A befriends B the relationship roles are the same, and if I invoke B's friends I should get a list with A in it. This is the problematic code in full:

```
friendship = Table(
    'friendships', Base.metadata,
    Column('friend_a_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('friend_b_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    friends = relationship('User',
                           secondary=friendship,
                           primaryjoin=id==friendship.c.friend_a_id,
                           secondaryjoin=id==friendship.c.friend_b_id,
                           #HELP NEEDED HERE
                           )
```

Sorry if this is too much text, I just want to be as explicit as I can with this. I can't seem to find any reference material to this on the web.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's the UNION approach I hinted at on the mailing list earlier today.

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Table, Column, ForeignKey, \
    create_engine, String, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base= declarative_base()

friendship = Table(
    'friendships', Base.metadata,
    Column('friend_a_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), 
                                        primary_key=True),
    Column('friend_b_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), 
                                        primary_key=True)
)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    # this relationship is used for persistence
    friends = relationship("User", secondary=friendship, 
                           primaryjoin=id==friendship.c.friend_a_id,
                           secondaryjoin=id==friendship.c.friend_b_id,
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return "User(%r)" % self.name

# this relationship is viewonly and selects across the union of all
# friends
friendship_union = select([
                        friendship.c.friend_a_id, 
                        friendship.c.friend_b_id
                        ]).union(
                            select([
                                friendship.c.friend_b_id, 
                                friendship.c.friend_a_id]
                            )
                    ).alias()
User.all_friends = relationship('User',
                       secondary=friendship_union,
                       primaryjoin=User.id==friendship_union.c.friend_a_id,
                       secondaryjoin=User.id==friendship_union.c.friend_b_id,
                       viewonly=True) 

e = create_engine("sqlite://",echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(e)
s = Session(e)

u1, u2, u3, u4, u5 = User(name='u1'), User(name='u2'), \
                    User(name='u3'), User(name='u4'), User(name='u5')

u1.friends = [u2, u3]
u4.friends = [u2, u5]
u3.friends.append(u5)
s.add_all([u1, u2, u3, u4, u5])
s.commit()

print u2.all_friends
print u5.all_friends
```

Comment: This seems to be a bit error-prone: you can accidentally append to `all_friends` and you won't get any warning. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also this allows for duplicate friendships with swapped ids (like `1, 2` and `2, 1`).  You can put a constraint that one id is greater than another, but then you need to keep track of which users can be appended to which users `friends` attribute.

Comment: viewonly=True has no bearing on the behavior of the collection in Python.  If you're truly concerned about appends to this collection, you can use collection_cls and apply a list or set type that has the mutation methods overridden to throw a NotImplementedError or similar.

Comment: as far as 1->2 + 2->1, different systems can take different opinions on this.  In the example above, it won't cause any "problems" directly because User.all_friends when it populates will de-duplicate User objects based on identity.   A real-world "friends" system may want to apply additional data onto each "friend" relationship - User 1 may say (s)he knows User 2 via "work", whereas User 2 might report knowing User 1 via "school", and the system might want to store both of those facts, e.g. this is a directed graph.  
(cont)

Comment: If OTOH you want to limit it to one edge between any two User objects, it could be as easy as applying a SQL-level constraint (though this would require a SELECT-per-insert and I might be concerned about performance), and on the Python side you just check the "all_friends" collection upon append using an [append event](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/events.html?highlight=append#sqlalchemy.orm.events.AttributeEvents.append)

Comment: @zzzeek Can you confirm that this is still the best way or point to the current best way to get this kind of unordered/non-directional self-referential many to many relationship with sqlalchemy?

Comment: I just got my code working with your first half of the answer, in what case would you need the `all_friends` bit over just `friends`?

Comment: if you don't need the all_friends part then you don't need it!

Comment: @zzzeek Why do you need a separate relationship for persistence vs view-only? Normally 1 relationship works fine for both.

Answer (score 14):

I needed to solve this same problem and messed about quite a lot with self referential many-to-many relationship wherein I was also subclassing the `User` class with a `Friend` class and running into `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError`. In the end instead of creating a self referential many-to-many relationship, I created a self referential one-to-many relationship using a join table (or secondary table).

If you think about it, with self referential objects, one-to-many IS many-to-many. It solved the issue of the backref in the original question.

I also have a gisted [working example](https://gist.github.com/tr3buchet/a9f10e5923985e3727e8) if you want to see it in action. Also it looks like [github](https://github.com) formats gists containing ipython notebooks now. Neat.

```
friendship = Table(
    'friendships', Base.metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), index=True),
    Column('friend_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id')),
    UniqueConstraint('user_id', 'friend_id', name='unique_friendships'))


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))

    friends = relationship('User',
                           secondary=friendship,
                           primaryjoin=id==friendship.c.user_id,
                           secondaryjoin=id==friendship.c.friend_id)

    def befriend(self, friend):
        if friend not in self.friends:
            self.friends.append(friend)
            friend.friends.append(self)

    def unfriend(self, friend):
        if friend in self.friends:
            self.friends.remove(friend)
            friend.friends.remove(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User(name=|%s|)>' % self.name
```