# Self-referencing many-to-many relationship with an association object in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, self-referencing-table

I've found examples for a self-referencing many-to-many relationship with an association table. How can I achieve the same using an association object?

The code below is based on: [How can I achieve a self-referencing many-to-many relationship on the SQLAlchemy ORM back referencing to the same attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116924/how-can-i-achieve-a-self-referencing-many-to-many-relationship-on-the-sqlalchemy)

```py
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from db.common import Base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

M2M = Table('m2m',
            Base.metadata,
            Column('entity_parent_id', 
                   Integer,
                   ForeignKey('entity.id'),
                   primary_key=True),
            Column('entity_child_id',
                   Integer,
                   ForeignKey('entity.id'), 
                   primary_key=True),
)


class Entity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entity'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    entity_childs = relationship("Entity",
                                    secondary=M2M,
                                    primaryjoin="Enity.id==m2m.c.entity_parent_id",
                                    secondaryjoin="Enity.id==m2m.c.entity_child_id",
                                    )

    entity_parents = relationship("Entity",
                                     secondary=M2M,
                                     primaryjoin="Enity.id==m2m.c.entity_child_id",
                                     secondaryjoin="Enity.id==m2m.c.entity_parent_id",
                                     )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach uses an association object instead of an association table to get a self-referencing many-to-many relationship:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, create_engine, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class EntityAssociation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entity_association'

    entity_parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('entity.id'), primary_key=True)
    entity_child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('entity.id'), primary_key=True)

class Entity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entity'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    entity_childs = relationship('Entity',
                                 secondary='entity_association',
                                 primaryjoin=id==EntityAssociation.entity_parent_id,
                                 secondaryjoin=id==EntityAssociation.entity_child_id,
                                 backref='childs')

    entity_parents = relationship('Entity',
                                  secondary='entity_association',
                                  primaryjoin=id==EntityAssociation.entity_child_id,
                                  secondaryjoin=id==EntityAssociation.entity_parent_id,
                                  backref='parents')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Entity(name={self.name})>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(engine)

    db = Session()

    parent1 = Entity(name='parent1')
    parent2 = Entity(name='parent2')
    child1 = Entity(name='child1')
    child2 = Entity(name='child2')

    parent1.entity_childs = [child1, child2]
    parent2.entity_childs = [child2]

    db.add(parent1)
    db.add(parent2)
    db.add(child1)
    db.add(child2)
    db.commit()

    entities = db.query(Entity).all()
    for entity in entities:
        print(entity)
        print('   Parent: ', entity.entity_parents)
        print('   Childs: ', entity.entity_childs)
        print()
```

This will have the following result:

```py
<Entity(name=parent1)>
   Parent:  []
   Childs:  [<Entity(name=child1)>, <Entity(name=child2)>]

<Entity(name=child1)>
   Parent:  [<Entity(name=parent1)>]
   Childs:  []

<Entity(name=child2)>
   Parent:  [<Entity(name=parent1)>, <Entity(name=parent2)>]
   Childs:  []

<Entity(name=parent2)>
   Parent:  []
   Childs:  [<Entity(name=child2)>]
```

Comment: Hello rfkortekass. Thank you very much for your answer and for the edit of my question. It works fine. My problem was to get the primaryjoin and secondaryjoin to the right way. I think I have to figure out, what a joinobject is exactly.