# Self referencing many-to-many relationship with extra column in association object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, associations, self-referencing-table

I am new in Sqlalchemy and trying to achieve the following goal with `relationship()`:

1. There is an `User` table which stores user data.
2. Every user is able to invite other user with an `invite_code`.
3. Every user keeps a list of `invitation`, every `invitation` includes the `invite_code` and the invitee `User`

I think the relationship between `User` and `Invitation` is one-to-many. Since `Invitation` contains `User`, then I think it is probably better to use self-referential relationship to represent the inviter-to-invitaions(invitees) relationship and use an association object to store the `invite_code`.

I checked the [sqlalchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many) and the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424424/self-referencing-many-to-many-relationship-with-an-association-object-in-sqlalch), tried to implement the classed like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, create_engine, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Invitation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'invitation'

    invite_code = Column(Integer)
    inviter_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    invitee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    
    invitee = relationship('User') #Need HELP here

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    inviters = relationship('User',
                            secondary='invitation',
                            primaryjoin=id==Invitation.invitee_id,
                            secondaryjoin=id==Invitation.inviter_id,
                            backref='invitees')

    invitations = relationship('Invitation')# Need HELP here

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'User: {self.name}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(engine)

    db = Session()

    inviter1 = User(name='inviter1')
    inviter2 = User(name='inviter2')

    invitee1= User(name='invitee1')
    invitee2 = User(name='invitee2')

    inviter1.invitees = [invitee1, invitee2]
    inviter2.invitees = [invitee1]

    db.add(inviter1)
    db.add(inviter2)
    db.add(invitee1)
    db.add(invitee2)
    db.commit()

    users = db.query(User).all()
    for user in users:
        print(user)
        print(' Inviter: ', user.inviters)
        print(' Invitee: ', user.invitees)
        print()
```

If the lines with comment `#Need HELP here` are deleted, I can get the corresponding inviters and invitees, but cannot get the `invite_code`. If the `#Need HELP here` code are added, the error is:

```
Exception has occurred: AmbiguousForeignKeysError
Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Invitation.invitee - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

Is there a way to add extra data column in association object like [association object for many-to-many relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) for self referential table?

Sorry for the too much text, I didn't find any reference document on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured it out with the help of `foreign_keys`:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, create_engine, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    sent_invitations = relationship('Invitation', foreign_keys='Invitation.inviter_id', back_populates='inviter', cascade='all, delete')
    received_invitations=relationship('Invitation', foreign_keys='Invitation.invitee_id', back_populates='invitee', cascade='all, delete')
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'User: {self.name}'


class Invitation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'invitation'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    invite_code = Column(Integer)
    inviter_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    invitee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    
    inviter=relationship('User', foreign_keys=[inviter_id], back_populates='sent_invitations')
    invitee=relationship('User', foreign_keys=[invitee_id], back_populates='received_invitations')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Invitation: {self.inviter} invited {self.invitee} with {self.invite_code}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(engine)

    db = Session()

    inviter1 = User(name='inviter1')
    inviter2 = User(name='inviter2')

    invitee1= User(name='invitee1')
    invitee2 = User(name='invitee2')

    invitation1 = Invitation(invite_code=50, inviter=inviter1, invitee=invitee1)
    invitation2 = Invitation(invite_code=20, inviter=inviter2, invitee=invitee2)
    invitation3 = Invitation(invite_code=22, inviter=inviter1, invitee=inviter2)
    invitation4 = Invitation(invite_code=44, inviter=invitee1, invitee=inviter2)
    db.add(inviter1)
    db.add(inviter2)
    db.add(invitee1)
    db.add(invitee2)
    db.commit()

    users = db.query(User).all()
    for user in users:
        print(user)
        print(' sent_invitation: ', user.sent_invitations)
        print(' received_invitation: ', user.received_invitations)
        print()

    invitations = db.query(Invitation).all()
    for invitation in invitations:
        print(invitation)

    db.delete(inviter1)
    db.delete(invitee2)
    db.commit()
```